# How to update code to avoid "Undefined value"?

Tags: javascript

Recently I was working on a project with this extension and I have noticed that when I select "FIELD" option and enter a value everything works fine. But after I delete value from field and push enter whole app crash because of undefined value. Maybe someone could help me with code how to avoid this annoying crash?

Thx in advance!

Here is whole code.

```
/*global define*/
define(["qlik"], function(qlik) {
    'use strict';
    var BTN_SELECTED = 'qui-button-selected',
        BTN = 'qui-button',
        SELECT = 'qui-select',
         INPUT = 'qui-input';

    function createVariable(name) {
        var app = qlik.currApp();
        //from 2.1: check if variable exists
        if (app.variable.getByName) {
            app.variable.getByName(name).then(function() {
                //variable already exist
            }, function() {
                //create variable
                app.variable.create(name);
            });
        } else {
            //create variable - ignore errors
            app.variable.create(name);
        }
    }

    function createElement(tag, cls, html) {
        var el = document.createElement(tag);
        if (cls) {
            el.className = cls;
        }
        if (html !== undefined) {
            el.innerHTML = html;
        }
        return el;
    }
    return {
        initialProperties: {
            variableValue: {},
            variableName: "",
            render: "f",
            defaultValue: 0,
            alternatives: []
        },
        definition: {
            type: "items",
            component: "accordion",
            items: {
                settings: {
                    uses: "settings",
                    items: {
                        variable: {
                            type: "items",
                            label: "Variable",
                            items: {
                                name: {
                                    ref: "variableName",
                                    label: "Name",
                                    type: "string",
                                    change: function(data) {
                                        createVariable(data.variableName);
                                        data.variableValue.qStringExpression = '=' + data.variableName;
                                    }
                                },
                                render: {
                                    type: "string",
                                    component: "dropdown",
                                    label: "Render as",
                                    ref: "render",
                                    options: [{
                                        value: "b",
                                        label: "Button"
                                    }, {
                                        value: "s",
                                        label: "Select"
                                    }, {
                                        value: "f",
                                        label: "Field"
                                    }, {
                                        value: "l",
                                        label: "Slider"
                                    }],
                                    defaultValue: "f"
                                },
                                emptyVal: {
                                    ref: "emptyVal",
                                    label: "default(when empty)",
                                    type: "string",
                                    defaultValue: 0
                                },
                                alternatives: {
                                    type: "array",
                                    ref: "alternatives",
                                    label: "Alternatives",
                                    itemTitleRef: "label",
                                    allowAdd: true,
                                    allowRemove: true,
                                    addTranslation: "Add Alternative",
                                    items: {
                                        value: {
                                            type: "string",
                                            ref: "value",
                                            label: "Value"
                                        },
                                        label: {
                                            type: "string",
                                            ref: "label",
                                            label: "Label",
                                            expression: "optional"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    show: function(data) {
                                        return data.render === "b" || data.render === "s";
                                    }
                                },
                                min: {
                                    ref: "min",
                                    label: "Min",
                                    type: "number",
                                    defaultValue: 0,
                                    show: function(data) {
                                        return data.render === "l";
                                    }
                                },
                                max: {
                                    ref: "max",
                                    label: "Max",
                                    type: "number",
                                    defaultValue: 100,
                                    show: function(data) {
                                        return data.render === "l";
                                    }
                                },
                                step: {
                                    ref: "step",
                                    label: "Step",
                                    type: "number",
                                    defaultValue: 1,
                                    show: function(data) {
                                        return data.render === "l";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        paint: function($element, layout) {
            var wrapper = createElement('div'),
                ext = this;
            empty = layout.emptyVal;
            if (layout.render === 'b') {
                layout.alternatives.forEach(function(alt) {
                    var clazz = alt.value === layout.variableValue ? BTN_SELECTED : BTN;
                    var btn = createElement('button', clazz, alt.label);
                    btn.onclick = function() {
                        qlik.currApp(ext).variable.setContent(layout.variableName, alt.value);
                    }
                    wrapper.appendChild(btn);
                });
            } else if (layout.render === 's') {
                var sel = createElement('select', SELECT);
                layout.alternatives.forEach(function(alt) {
                    var opt = createElement('option', undefined, alt.label);
                    opt.value = alt.value;
                    opt.selected = alt.value === layout.variableValue;
                    sel.appendChild(opt);
                });
                sel.onchange = function() {
                    qlik.currApp(ext).variable.setContent(layout.variableName, this.value);
                }
                wrapper.appendChild(sel);
            } else if (layout.render === 'l') {
                var range = createElement('input');
                range.type = 'range';
                range.min = layout.min || 0;
                range.max = layout.max || 100;
                range.step = layout.step || 1;
                range.value = layout.variableValue;
                range.title = layout.variableValue;
                range.style.width = '98%';
                range.onchange = function() {
                    qlik.currApp(ext).variable.setContent(layout.variableName, this.value);
                }
                wrapper.appendChild(range);
            } else {
                var fld = createElement('input', INPUT);
                fld.type = 'number';
                fld.value = layout.variableValue;
                fld.onchange = function () {
                    if (this.value != "undifined") {
                        qlik.currApp(ext).variable.setContent(layout.variableName, this.value);
                    } else {
                        qlik.currApp(ext).variable.setContent(layout.variableName, 0);
                    }
                }
                wrapper.appendChild(fld);
            }
            var elem = $element[0];
            if (elem.childNodes.length === 0) {
                elem.appendChild(wrapper);
            } else {
                elem.replaceChild(wrapper, elem.childNodes[0]);
            }
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: Where is the php part?

Comment: Please point out the specific point in your 207 lines of code where something is `undefined`. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Probably problem is somewhere in this part of the code:

                fld.type = 'number';
                fld.value = layout.variableValue;
                fld.onchange = function () {
                    if (this.value != "undifined") {
                        qlik.currApp(ext).variable.setContent(layout.variableName, this.value);
                    } else {
                        qlik.currApp(ext).variable.setContent(layout.variableName, 0);
                    }
                }
                wrapper.appendChild(fld);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (this.value != "undifined") {
```

Here, you are comparing `value` to the **string** `"undifined"` (which is also mistyped).

---

It seems you want to compare to the **value** `undefined`:

```
if (this.value !== undefined) {
```

or check the data type of `value`:

```
if (typeof this.value != "undefined") {
```